# commit on MySql + Zeos lib

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, zeos

I use next code to post some records on a non autocommin connection:

```
ZConnection1.AutoCommit := False;

  try
    ZTable1.Insert;
    ZTable1.FieldByName('name').AsString := 'John Doe';
    ZTable1.Post;
    ZConnection1.Commit;
  except
    ZConnection1.Rollback;
  end;
```

When I run this code nothing is saved on my database.

After I try next code ...

```
ZConnection1.AutoCommit := False;

   with ZQuery1 do begin
      SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO mytable (name) values ("John Doe")';
      ExecSQL;
      SQL.Text := SQL.Text + 'COMMIT' ;
      try
        ExecSQL;
      except
        SQL.Text := 'ROLLBACK';
        ExecSQL;
      end;
    end;
```

... all work perfect.

What I do wrong on first case? I use Delphi6, MySql, Zeos library and InnoDB table.

Comment: Have you actually activated/opened the table before calling the code you have shown?

Comment: Yes, all are opened. I belive that in case of inactive table Delphi report it as error. I don't get any error message.

Comment: Yes it does but you had the insert within the try and didn't mention the exact error message...

Answer (score 8):

Have fixed my problem:

This is how `AutoCommit` property actually works in Zeos:

- when `AutoCommit` is True, then the transactions are commited automatically after each executed SQL statement, but you can use the `StartTransaction` command explicitly to prevent this auto commiting, until you explicitly call `Commit`.
- when `AutoCommit` is False, you shouldn't call `StartTransaction`. Then the transaction is started automatically, but it will not commit automatically after every executed statement.

```
ZConnection1.AutoCommit := True;
ZConnection1.StartTransaction;
try
  ZTable1.Insert;
  ZTable1.FieldByName('name').AsString := 'John Doe';
  ZTable1.Post;
  ZConnection1.Commit;
except
  ZConnection1.Rollback;
end;
```